# What does pygame.display.set_mode() do?

Tags: python, pygame

I have recently started learning python and decided that a fun way to learn would be to use pygame.

The following is some code that sets up the the window.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
```

Would `pygame` be a file in which the file `display` is located?
I assume `display` refers to a file in which the method `set_mode()` is located.

Comment: I misinterpreted you issue, you're asking specifically about this object notation, `display` is a singleton object on the `pygame` instance, nothing to do with files specifically here.

Comment: @Chris Schaller Thank you. I think my main question is if `display` is a class? I remembered reading that all classes are written with the first letter capitalized to differentiate classes from file names & methods.

Comment: Um, I don't want to be rude, just throw that memory in the bin, however valid it was at the time it will not serve you well going into this programming journey... There are many discussions about conventions for class, property and variable names that all have their merits, I've never heard one about differentiating from file names, references in your code are almost always objects or values, and certainly not files, unless your runtime creates an object to represent each file... Start with the basics, you'll see.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a basic understanding of Object-Oriented Programming but are learning python through pygame, then Have a read through this tutorial: [pygame - Setting Display Modes](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/DisplayModes.html#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20display%20mode%20in%20pygame%20creates%20a,nothing%20more%20than%20a%20standard%20pygame%20surface%20object.)

> Setting the display mode in pygame creates a visible image surface on the monitor. This surface can either cover the full screen or be windowed on platforms that support a window manager. The display surface is nothing more than a standard pygame surface object.

If you are starting to learn python and or programming from scratch, you might find more value in learning some basic programming and problem-solving concepts first, then come back to pygame.

I'm not affiliated but find the [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com) 30-day challenge as a great learning tool, it is unique in tutorial sites as it is language agnostic and allows you to learn multiple languages at the same time if you wish to do so! It is also a good environment to learn in as there are fewer IDE features, forcing you to understand more before you can move on.

> The average desktop IDE is not a great place to learn how to program because it will often have features like [Intellisense](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24580/intellisense), *Autocomplete* and other smart refactoring tools that allow us to write code quickly, but they allow you to "cheat" and skip over vital underlying mechanics that you need to understand if want to take advantage of abstract knowledge resources you may find around the web, like solutions in Stack Overflow!

Once you have a better understanding of syntax and how to use your chosen IDE, then go back to your pygame learning, walk before you run.

Comment: Updated my response with more information, welcome @carx207 to Stack Overflow, I wish you well on your programming journey!